# should I use "is" or "are" in this phrase?

Tags: word-usage

I'm glad at least one of us are thinking.

should I use are or is in the phrase above?

Answer (score 3):

Always try to eliminate extra words when determining this — in this case, ask whether using "are" still makes sense if you remove the "of us" phrase qualifying "one" from the sentence, plus the preamble.

> One are thinking.

vs

> One is thinking.

This way you can clearly see that the latter is correct since, as bcc32 indicates, "one" is the subject and is singular.

Answer (score 0):

*is* is correct.  The subject is *one*, not *us*, as in, "one person is thinking".